source_nodes is blank when using FunctionCallingAgentWorker in llama-index
from llama_index.core.agent import FunctionCallingAgentWorker
from llama_index.core.agent import AgentRunner

agent_worker = FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tools(
    tool_retriever=obj_retriever,
    llm=llm, 
    system_prompt=""" \
You are an agent designed to answer queries over a set of given papers.
Please always use the tools provided to answer a question. Do not rely on prior knowledge.\

""",
    verbose=True
)
agent = AgentRunner(agent_worker)

response = agent.query(
    "ask questions"
)

print(response)

Response(response='desired answer', source_nodes=[], metadata=None)
when i use this function , i want the sources_nodes to fetch the metadata from which it referred

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
